# How to prove (approximate) inequalities involving exponential (logarithms) and polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, functional-inequalities

How to prove the following inequality

$$(1-x) \ln(1-x) \geq -x + x^2/2\, \textrm{ for } x\in(0,1)?$$

In general how should one go about proving/approximating exponential and logarithms to get the following type of inequalities.

$$
e^{-x} \leq 1 - x + \frac{x^2}2,\; \textrm{ when } x\geq 0
$$

$$
e^{-x} \leq 1 - x/2,\;\; \textrm{ for } x \in [0,1.59]
$$

$$
\ln(1+x) \geq x/2,\;\; \textrm{ for } x \in [0,2.5]
$$

You could find more of these [here](http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf).

Comment: First inequality can be proved using the Taylor Series of $e^{-x}$

Comment: You could use calculus. Prove that the endpoints fulfill the inequality, that the expression is a nice behaved differentiable function and that nothing interesting happens inside the interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite trivial that
$$ -1-\log(1-t)\geq -1+t \tag{1} $$
holds for any $t\in(0,1)$, hence by considering some $x\in(0,1)$ and applying $\int_{0}^{x}(\ldots)\,dt $ to both sides of $(1)$ the claim follows in a straightforward way.

A much more accurate approximation is
$$ \forall x\in(0,1),\qquad (1-x)\log(1-x) \geq \frac{x \left(-6+3 x+2 x^2\right)}{6-x^2}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Can I know how you obtained the better approximation? Given a new region and function, I would like to know how to find tight lower-bounds and upper-bounds?

Comment: @GraspIt: the RHS of $(2)$ divided by $(1-x)$ is a Padé approximant for $\log(1-x)$. You may prove that the inequality holds over $(0,1)$ by considering the Taylor series of $\log(1-x)$ and performing a termwise comparison with the Taylor series of $\frac{x(-6+3x+2x^2)}{(6-x^2)(1-x)}$. Indeed I found such approximation by just walking in the opposite direction, from Taylor series to inequalities.

Comment: I see. I know that Taylor series of $\log (1-x)$ is $-x - \frac{x^2}2 - \frac{x^3}3 \cdots$, but how do I truncate the series to get the approximation that you got?

Comment: @GraspIt: no. Compute the whole Taylor series of $(1-x)(6-x^2)\log(1-x)$ and compare it, term-by-term, with the Taylor series of $x(-6+3x+2x^2)$. The difference is a Taylor series with non-negative coefficients, hence $(1-x)(6-x^2)\log(1-x)\geq x(-6+3x+2x^2)$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

We can rewrite it to 
$$\cases{f(x) = (1-x)\ln(1-x)+x-\frac{x^2}2\\f(x) \geq 0, x\in[0,1]}$$

Now showing that $f$ is differentiable on the interval is easy so we skip that part.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\ln(1-x) - \frac{1-x}{1-x} + 1 -x = -x-\ln(1-x)$$
The zeros are where:
$$e^x = \frac 1 {1-x}$$
solved by $x=0$ and no other x in the interval $[0,1]$

Now what remains is to calculate $f(0),f(1)$ (or their limits) and draw conclusions.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a systematic way to prove the inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1-x)-\frac{x^2-2x}{2(1-x)}$.

Hence, $f'(x)=\frac{x^2}{2(1-x)^2}>0$, which says $f(x)>f(0)=0$ and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing $x$ by $1-x$ we can see that the inequality is transformed into $$2x\log x\geq x^2-1$$ for $x\in(0,1)$. Consider $$f(x) =2x\log x-x^{2}+1,f(0)=1$$ so that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ with derivative $$f'(x) =2+2\log x-2x=2(\log x - x+1)$$ Next we note that $\log x\leq x-1$ so that $f'(x) \leq 0$ and hence $f(x) \geq f(1)=0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ and we are done.